# How do i pipe stdout/stderr in .NET?

Tags: .net, ipc, stdout, stderr

I want to do something like this

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f flac - | oggenc2.exe - -o audio.ogg
```

i know how to do `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f flac` using the process class in .NET but how do i pipe it to oggenc2?

Any example of how to do this (it doesnt need to be ffmpeg or oggenc2) would be fine.

Comment: Are you calling a process from within a .NET app, or trying to replicate that argument format for your own console app?

Comment: what do you mean by replicate that argument? you mean to take in arguements like ffmpeg/oggenc2 does? no i would like to call these fron my .NET app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I wrote the following code to do this:

```
    Process ffmpeg = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
            Arguments = "-i audio.mp3 -f flac -",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        }
    };
    Process oggenc2 = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "oggenc2.exe",
            Arguments = "- -o audio.ogg",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        }
    };

    ffmpeg.Start();
    oggenc2.Start();

    int bufferLength = 4096;
    var input = oggenc2.StandardInput.BaseStream;
    var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;

    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(input))
    {
        using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(output))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = r.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
    }

    ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
```

Hope, this helps.